# Moving average of cumulative points

Tags: stata

Let's say a have a dataset with teams' scores over many matches, aggregated at a daily level. How could I compute a moving average of the last 10 matches?
Important: some teams may have played more than once per day. I have something like this:

| Date | Team | Score | Match id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01Jan2021 | Team A | 3 | 1 |
| 01Jan2021 | Team A | 2 | 2 |
| 02Jan2021 | Team A | 4 | 3 |
| 02Jan2021 | Team B | 4 | 3 |

etc. Note that race_id may be repeated, since more Teams A and B may have competed against each other.

Basically, I need to get the moving average of scores of each given team, considering the last 10 matches it was featured in (if it played less than 10, then the moving average of the total number of matches).

Comment: So, there could have been 9 matches in so many days and 2 more in the day before? We need more precise rules and a data example.

Comment: Exactly. What I need is a column with a moving average of this scores which considers only the last 10 matches. 
Data is aggregated daily, and then by team (a long format). I have a field which is an id for the matches, so I was thinking about counting those to somehow meet the condition of calculating the moving average for only the last 10 matches. As stated before, a given team may have played more than once in the same day.

Comment: We are still lacking a data example -- a word description is not a data example -- and you don't give your rules for when the number of games in an interval of days is not 10.

Comment: I edited the original post with a mock table of my data structure.

Comment: Different matches can get the same identifier?

Comment: No. Match ids are unique all along the dataset.

Comment: So why are two matches both 3 in your example?

Comment: That's the same match (feature both teams A and B). Sorry I didn't explain it right. ID's refer to single matches, but may be repeated across data due to the way it's aggregated.

Comment: That helps, but sorry without a full and realistic data example there still seem to be ambiguities as it's not clear (e.g.) how you identify the last 10 matches for a team, whether you're wanting a separate average for each team, and so forth. I won't keep asking little questions. Possibly `rangestat` from SSC may be of help. Back to you.